# SO closure text alignment

Tags: bug, design, close-dialog

This is hardly a major issue, but in pursuit of standards, I noticed that the styling (and standard) of the descriptors in the closure dialog box is somewhat **lower** than expected:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too, then couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I saw it 3-4 times, but can't reproduce it now either. CSS caching foo probably although I can't confirm.

Comment: It happens when there is a count at the end of the sentence.